# Yii 1.1 : Loading data (coming from API) in Yii Grid View

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, yii

I have an API endpoint which will give a response json when queried.

Here is the response object:

```
[
    {
        "number": 1,
        "name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "name": "DEF"
    },
  ]
```

I want to show it in the GridView but I don't know how to do it, because I'm not sure how to call push the json data (coming from API) in a data provider.

Below is the part where the grid loads

```
$this->widget('ext.jgridview.JGridView', array(
    'id' => $id,
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'ajaxUpdate' => isset($dependency)||isset($relation)?true:false,
    'enablePagination' => true,
    'template' => '{pager} {items} {pager}',    // '{summary} {items} {pager}',
    'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
    'summaryText' => true,
    'summaryText' => Yii::t('app', 'Displaying {start}-{end} of {count} results.'),
    'columns' => $columns,
    'pager' => array(
        'class' => 'booster.widgets.TbPager',
        'displayFirstAndLast' => true,
        'alignment' => TbPager::ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
        'maxButtonCount' => Yii::app()->params['pagerMaxButtonCount'],
        'prevPageLabel' => '&lt;',
        'nextPageLabel' => '&gt;',
        'firstPageLabel' => '&lt;&lt;',
        'lastPageLabel' => '&gt;&gt;',
     ),
    'selectableRows' => null,
));
```

Data provider in model-> search() looks like this

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    '*',
                ),
            ),
            'pagination' => $pageSize<1000 ? array('pageSize' => $pageSize) : false,
        ));
```

What are the changes required to achieve the aforementioned??
Any example code which is targeted for Yii version 1.1 would help.